# Working With Variadic Functions C++

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I am using variadic function in one of my programs. Here is definition of it -

```
std::string GetMessage(const char *format,...)
```

Now I would like to give extra feasibility to user to provide plain string is he wants to.
Like - `GetMessage("Here is my message")`

I facing trouble while processing such inputs , inputs with variable is working fine.

I tried with

```
val_list vl;
va_start(vl,format);

if(strlen(vl) > 1) // TO check if va list has any arguments.
```

But it has very in-consistent behavior.

So can somebody please suggest me better way to know if variadic function has arguments OR No arguments?

Comment: Post the implementation of `GetMessage`. *"I facing trouble"* is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caller has to actively pass some values that let the called var/stdarg-using function know where the arguments end.  Common techniques include:

- passing a sentinel value, such as a trailing NULL
- passing a count
- passing a format string where embedded content (e.g. `%`-prefixed formats for `printf()` et al) imply the needed number of arguments

You can sometimes facilitate reliable use of your variadic function by calling them via macros that inject a sentinel, and some compilers let you piggy-back on their `printf()` style argument checks (e.g. GCC).

Comment: std::string GetMessage(const char *format,...)
{
    va_list vl;
    int i = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    va_start( vl, format );

    switch( format[i] ) {   // Type to expect.
        case 'c':
        {
            char c = va_arg(vl, char );          
            ss << c;
        }
        break;

    case 's':
        {
            char * str = va_arg(vl, char * );            
            ss << str;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    va_end( vl );
    return const_cast<char*>(ss.str().c_str());
}

Comment: @user987316 You don't need to use `return const_cast<char*>(ss.str().c_str());` - simply `return ss.str()`.  Critically, you'd want a `for(int i = 0; ; ++i)` loop after `va_start` and around the `switch` so you can handle multiple arguments.  `str` would be better as a `const char*` but that's not critical.

Comment: Is there any way to know if user has provided any variable arguments?? I would like to distiguish between GetMessage("%s %d",variable1,variable2) AND GetMessage("Function run completed"). I know for later part I can write like GetMessage("%s","Function run completed") but I think that is unnecessary and not a good code practice. Whats your take on this??

Comment: @user987316: sure there's a way... search for a `'%'` is the format string.  Another factor is whether you trust the string... consider `GetMessage("%s", username)` works if some cheeky user typed their username as "Bad %s %s Freddie", while `GetMessage(username)` will try to get two more pointers that aren't there - reading garbage values from the stack - then worse still it will follow those garbage pointers and try and use the presumed ASCIIZ text at the addresses they contain: it's likely to crash your app but could be carefully used to take over your account.